# How to delete a row when even one column of the row has a value less than one

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file with 7000 rows and 28 columns. How to delete a row when, even one of the 28 columns has a value less than one?

I found answers with `awk` wherein they delete a row when a column is specified.

But I want to delete the row irrespective of the column number that has value less than one.

My file is in tab delimited format.
example file

```
a       1       2       4       7       9
b       0.5     0.9     6       10      3
c       3       5       12      7       9
d       0.9     6       7       4       10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Awk, you would loop over the fields (columns) and test each one. Since your rows have a non-numeric first column, start at the second (`i=2`):

So

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i+0 < 1) next}} 1' file
```

Ex. given

```
$ cat example
a       1       2       4       7       9
b       0.5     0.9     6       10      3
c       3       5       12      7       9
d       7.96681779026634e-05     6       7       4       10
```

then

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i+0 < 1) next}} 1' example
a       1       2       4       7       9
c       3       5       12      7       9
```

In Perl you could `grep` the default split `@F` array after shifting out the first column:

```
perl -ane 'shift @F; print unless grep { $_ < 1 } @F' file
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to linux. Both outputs nothing. FYI, I have perl installed, perl 5, version 26, subversion 2 (v5.26.2)

Comment: @KousalyaDevi what is the format of your file? Please edit your question to include a minimal testable example (with a few rows and columns).

Comment: @KousalyaDevi please see revised answer in response to your updated question

Comment: My file  has exponential values. `awk` did not  recognise them while deleting the lines. `e.g. 7.96681779026634e-05` these values are still in the file. How to remove them?

Comment: @KousalyaDevi that shouldn't matter - see above