# How to delete rows where the non-zero elements are less than one

Tags: sed, awk

I want to delete rows where **all the non-zero elements** are less than one

My file is

```
a   2   0   0   0   9
b   3   0   0   0.7 13
c   0.3 0.5 0   0   0
d   0.4 7.96681779026634e-05    0       0
```

Output expected is

```
a   2   0   0   0   9
b   3   0   0   0.7 13
```

I am beginner. I tried `awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i+0=0 print $0; else < 1) next}} 1'` by editing a previous code as in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150595/how-to-delete-a-row-when-even-one-column-of-the-row-has-a-value-less-than-one/1150596#1150596), but I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk '{f=0; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0!=0 && $i+0>=1)f=1} f' file
a  2   0   0   0   9
b   3   0   0   0.7 13
```

The code uses a variable `f`.  If `f` ends up as true (nonzero), then we print the row.

- `f=0`

  For each row, start by setting `f` to false (don't print)
- `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0!=0 && $i+0>=1)f=1`

  If any element is non-zero and is greater than one, then set `f` to `1` (true).
- `f`

  If `f` is true (nonzero), print this row.